# How to find differences of two datasets in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to compare a table with an earlier backup and identify all the differences.

While it is really easy to find all the changed datasets (using the `MINUS` operator) it is rather hard to also select the name of the changed attribute (or for starters any changed attribute in case there were multiple attributes changed).

By now i found the differences by comparing the datasets manually, but i am still interested in a solution that would've printed out edited datasets as well as a changed attribute **without** hardcoding the column names into the query.

**Example:**

Backup-table (MyTable_Backup):

```
ID | Name | Value
-----------------
1  | Alie | 15
2  | Bob  | 7
3  | Eve  | 0
```

current table (MyTable):

```
ID | Name | Value
-----------------
1  | Alice| 15
2  | Bob  | 8
3  | Eve  | 0
```

expected output:

```
ID | Name | Value | DiffAttribute
---------------------------------
1  | Alice| 15    | Name
2  | Bob  | 8     | Value
```

Comment: could you give us your query that you were using?

Comment: Sorry for bad correction. Thought it was a typo.

Comment: Why is alice in the result when values are the same?

Comment: @Jeremy: The query i was using was just (select * from MyTable) MINUS (select * from MyTable_Backup)

Comment: jarlh: don't worry, i rolled it back. @artm: I want the full dataset from "MyTable" (not from "MyTable_Backup") plus the Name of the Attribute that was changed - in this case it was the Name.

Comment: what would you want behavior to be if both names and value are different?

Comment: Since the first answer already states to compare all attributes one-by-one: this is not what i am looking for. I thought about something like getting the attribute names from the table `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` and iterate over those, so this would be applicable to any table.

Comment: since you are using oracle just stick it into cursors and iterate one by one.

Comment: @Vladimir: Ideally the result will show the dataset twice (once for each difference found). However i will be able to include this myself later on, so if it is easier, it would be sufficient for now if the output contains the dataset only once and contains the "first" or "last" unmatched attribute.

Comment: You could create a procedure that loops through all the columns of mytable, checks if mytable.column = mytable_backup.column, if it doesn't write the id, the old value and the new value to a temporary table and at the end of the procedure select all the rows from that temporary table

Comment: @Jeremy could you expand on how to loop through all attributes without typing out the names? This is where i got stuck :)

Comment: BEGIN
   FOR columnItem IN (SELECT column_name 
                        FROM all_tab_columns 
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable')
   LOOP, however this isn't normal sql, this is a procedure, not sure if you've ever written one, it's more complicated than a normal query

Comment: to be honest I probably wouldn't even know how to finish that procedure

Comment: @VladimirOselsky can I use a cursor without specifying all ColumnNames in the `DECLARE` section? I would like to create a query (or procedure) in which i only need to specify the table name since i don't want to bind it to a specific table-structure.

Comment: @JeremyC. i don't know how to read the attribute-value of a given dataset/table if the attribute-name is only available as string. If I use something like `select  @stringVariable from [...]` it will obviously print me out the value of that variable.

Comment: well using the loop structure I gave 4 comments ago it would be something like select t1.id, t1.columnItem, t2.columnitem from mytable t1 join mytable_backup t2 on t1.id = t2.id where not t1.columnItem = t2.columnItem

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Select a.ID, a.Name, A.Value
     , case when a.Name <> B.Name and
                 a.Value <> B.Value
            then 'Name,Value'
            when a.Name <> B.Name then 'Name'
            when a.Value <> B.Value then 'Value'
            when b.value is null then 'Missing'
       end DiffAttribute
  from MyTable a
  left join MyTable_Backup b
    on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: sorry, this is just comparing the tables by hardcoding the columnnames into the query. Like I stated in the question i am only interested in a solution in which this can be avoided.